# "TypeError: path.substring is not a function" Node,js when I try to read a json sent with POST

Tags: jquery, node.js, json, ajax, express

I'm setting up a web server using Node.Js and I'm making a login POST request from a javascript script (using JQuery method %.post()). I don't understand where the problem is, but I'm pretty sure JSON file sent with data is not read correctly by the server, because when I use the values of my JSON file they are undefined

I'm using Node.js on my Windows 10 computer to reply POST and GET request

Server side:

```
var port = 8001;
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use('/', express.static('client'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    var username = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
        \\This returns "login successful undefined undefined"
    console.log('login successful ' + username + " " + password + "\n") ;
    var data = {
        email: username,
        password: password
    }
    res.sendFile(data);
})
```

Client side

```
function login(){
    var em = document.getElementById("emailForm").value;
    var psw = document.getElementById("passwordForm").value;

    var account = {
        "email": em,
        "password": psw
    }
    console.log(account.email + " : " + account.password);
    document.cookie = account;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8001/login",
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(account),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var resp = JSON.parse(response)
            alert(resp.status);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("error:\nStatus: " + status + "\nXHR: " + xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

The server side error message is:

TypeError: path.substring is not a function
    at exports.isAbsolute (C:\Users\39334\OneDrive\University\DA DARE\Programmazione web e mobile\Progetto\web-app\node_modules\express\lib\utils.js:59:23)

displayed on nodejs terminal

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are using `res.sendFile`, which requires you to specify an absolute url to a file.

As you are trying to respond with JSON you can use this instead:

```
res.json(data)
```

Also, you need to add `contentType` to your `$.ajax()` call to tell the server that you are sending JSON:

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  contentType: "application/json",
  // ...
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you very much. I want to add that in client side, on success request function, `var resp = JSON.parse(response)` is not necessary. Need to use `var resp = response`